Plotly contour graph and axis label position
I have a contour graph with the x axis text showing on the top. I am trying to move it to the bottom of the chart as in any normal scatter plot. I tried "position:0" and "position:1" as shown in https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/ but to no avail.
Anyone knows what else I could try?

Code:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as nump

# variables are initialised with x,y co-ordinates
cordof_x = nump.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
cordof_y = nump.arange(0, 10, 0.2)

# Colourscale
colorscale = [[0, '#FFC0CB'], [0.5, 'rgb(120,120,120)'], [1, '#0000FF']]

# A mesh is created with the given co-ordinates by this numpy function
[X, Y] = nump.meshgrid(cordof_x, cordof_y)
contour_function = nump.cos((X + 6) * (1 / 10)) + nump.sin((Y) * (-1 / 10))

contour_trace = go.Contour(x=cordof_x, y=cordof_y, z=contour_function, showscale=False, ncontours=40, colorscale=colorscale, hoverinfo='skip')
scatter_trace = go.Scatter(x=[8], y=[5], mode='markers', marker=dict(symbol='star-diamond-dot', color="#FFBF00", size=24, line=dict(color="black", width=3)))

contour_plot = go.Figure(data=[contour_trace, scatter_trace])
contour_plot.update_layout({
    "showlegend": False, "height":300, "width":300,
    "xaxis": {"title_text": "CategoryA", 'title_font': {"size": 22, "color": "black"}, "showticklabels": False, "dtick": 1, "range": [0, 10], "position":0},
    "yaxis": {"title_text": "CategoryB", 'title_font': {"size": 22, "color": "black"}, "showticklabels": False, "dtick": 1, "range": [0, 10]},
    "autosize": True, "plot_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", "paper_bgcolor": "white", "margin": dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0)})
contour_plot.show()


I have run your code in my environment and it gives me the graph you want. What version is currently being used? I am using 5.20.0.

@r-beginners indeed it was an issue with the versions. I had 5.18 and with 5.21 it looks as expected. Thanks!

This is caused by an old version of plotly. For versions above 5.20 the problem is solved.
Check your version with:
import plotly
print(plotly.__version__)

